# Change image when clicking a option tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image

I have two select tags in my HTML and I want to use these two select with the option to change a image, One of the select tags is called model and the other one is called color. When I want to click one of the models that are in the select tag, the image need to change to that model and then they can click on a color and the color of that model needs to change.

Does anyone have tips to make this happen.

HTML Code

```
                    <tr>    
                        <td><label>Model* :</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="model" required>
                              <option value="cortina-ecomo-life-transport">Cortina Ecomo Life Transport</option>
                              <option value="merida-TFS-100">Merida TFS-100</option>
                              <option value="cortina-transport-roots-3">Cortina Transport Roots 3</option>
                            </select>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td><label>Kleur* :</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="kleur" required>
                              <option value="zwart">Zwart</option>
                              <option value="blauw">Blauw</option>
                              <option value="groen">Groen</option>
                              <option value="geel">Geel</option>
                              <option value="rood">Rood</option>
                              <option value="bruin">Bruin</option>
                              <option value="paars">Paars</option>
                              <option value="wit">Wit</option>
                            </select>                               
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

I have nothing more then this at the moment, I already tried something with jquery but that didn't work.

[Like they did on this website](http://www.evilcontrollers.com/xbox-360-controller-creator.html)

It need to become something like this, when you click a option on there it changes

Comment: put some code, or what you tried to achieve it

Comment: Yea its possible, that's all I can say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.
You should rename your images based on the selection. model_colour.jpg. E.g: cortina_rood.jpg

```js
var imgsrc;
changeImage();

function changeImage() {
 imgsrc = $('#model').val() + '_' + $('#kleur').val() + '.jpg';
 $('#yourimage').attr('src', imgsrc);
}

$("#model").change(function() {
 changeImage();
});

$("#kleur").change(function() {
 changeImage();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
            <td><label>Model* :</label></td>
            <td>
                <select name="model" required id="model">
                  <option value="cortina">Cortina Ecomo Life Transport</option>
                  <option value="merida">Merida TFS-100</option>
                  <option value="cortina">Cortina Transport Roots 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Kleur* :</label></td>
            <td>
                <select name="kleur" required id="kleur">
                  <option value="zwart">Zwart</option>
                  <option value="blauw">Blauw</option>
                  <option value="groen">Groen</option>
                  <option value="geel">Geel</option>
                  <option value="rood">Rood</option>
                  <option value="bruin">Bruin</option>
                  <option value="paars">Paars</option>
                  <option value="wit">Wit</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <img src="" alt="" id="yourimage">
 </table>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```